# Heckman sample selection model panel data in SAS proc qlim

Tags: sas, panel-data

Is it possible to estimate a Heckman sample selection model on panel data in SAS's proc qlim?

I am trying to estimate the effect of a policy intervention (temporarely lower taxes) on turnover of companies active in the construction sector. The data are quarterly VAT declarations on firm level and I am using a diff-in-diff setup (i.e. I am comparing turnover in the construction sector to turnover in a control group).

The problem is that quite some companies in the construction sector are declaring zero turnover (i.e. company hasn't produced anything in a quarter but is required by tax administration to declare zero turnover) now and then (partly seasonally related). So the companies make two decisions; (1) turn on company y/n [extensive margin] and (2) how much to produce [intensive margin]. Part of the policy intervention's effect will be on (1).

So far I tried this in proc qlim with d being a dummy which is 1 if a firm declares turnover > 0 and 0 if turnover = 0 :

```
proc qlim data= dataset HECKIT;
     class timevariable;
     model d = quarter_dummies self_employed_dummy treatment_dummy
               policy_intervention_dummies / discrete; 
     model ln_turnover = quarter_dummies treatment_dummy
              policy_intervention_dummies / select(d=1);
```

run;

For the first stage I got results I could interpret well, but the results for the second stage were weird; very high effects and opposite signs. I guess I am doing something wrong. Do you perhaps know what's going wrong?

Best,
Eric